# Loss is “nan” when fine-tuning HuggingFace NLI model (both RoBERTa/BART)

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I'm using [HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/)'s Transformer's library and I’m trying to fine-tune a pre-trained NLI model (`ynie/roberta-large-snli_mnli_fever_anli_R1_R2_R3-nli`) on a dataset of around 276.000 hypothesis-premise pairs. I’m following the instructions from the docs [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html) and [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/training.html). I have the impression that the fine-tuning works (it does the training and saves the checkpoints), but `trainer.train()` and `trainer.evaluate()` return "nan" for the loss.

**What I've tried:**

- I tried using both `ynie/roberta-large-snli_mnli_fever_anli_R1_R2_R3-nli` and `facebook/bart-large-mnli` to make sure that it's not linked to specific model, but I get the issue for both models
- I tried following the advice in this [related github issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/1727), but adding `num_labels=3` to the config file does not solve the issue. (I think my issue is different because the models are already fine-tuned on NLI in my case)
- I tried many different ways of changing my input data because I suspected that there could be an issue with my input data, but I also couldn't solve it that way.
- **The probable source of the issue:** *I inspected the prediction output from the model during training and the weird thing is the prediction value always seems to be "0" (entailment) in 100% of cases (see printed output in the code below). This is clearly an error. I think the source for this is that the logits the model seems to return during training are `torch.tensor([[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]])` and when you apply `.argmax(-1)` to this, you get torch.tensor(0). The big mystery for me is why the logits would become "nan", because the model does not do that when I use the same input data only outside of the trainer.
  => Does anyone know where this issues comes from? See my code below.*

Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestion!

#### Here is my code:

```
### load model & tokenize
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
import torch

max_length = 256
hg_model_hub_name = "ynie/roberta-large-snli_mnli_fever_anli_R1_R2_R3-nli"
# also tried: hg_model_hub_name = "facebook/bart-large-mnli"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(hg_model_hub_name)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(hg_model_hub_name)
model.config

device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
print(f"Device: {device}")
if device == "cuda":
  model = model.half()
model.to(device)
model.train();

#... some data preprocessing

encodings_train = tokenizer(premise_train, hypothesis_train, return_tensors="pt", max_length=max_length,
                            return_token_type_ids=True, truncation=False, padding=True)
encodings_val = tokenizer(premise_val, hypothesis_val, return_tensors="pt", max_length=max_length,
                          return_token_type_ids=True, truncation=False, padding=True)
encodings_test = tokenizer(premise_test, hypothesis_test, return_tensors="pt", max_length=max_length,
                           return_token_type_ids=True, truncation=False, padding=True)


### create pytorch dataset object
class XDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings, labels):
        self.encodings = encodings
        self.labels = labels
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = {key: torch.as_tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
        #item = {key: torch.as_tensor(val[idx]).to(device) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
        item['labels'] = torch.as_tensor(self.labels[idx])
        #item['labels'] = self.labels[idx]
        return item
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

dataset_train = XDataset(encodings_train, label_train)
dataset_val = XDataset(encodings_val, label_val)
dataset_test = XDataset(encodings_test, label_test)

# compute metrics with trainer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_recall_fscore_support
def compute_metrics(pred):
    labels = pred.label_ids
    print(labels)
    preds = pred.predictions.argmax(-1)
    print(preds)
    precision, recall, f1, _ = precision_recall_fscore_support(labels, preds, average='binary', pos_label=0)
    acc = accuracy_score(labels, preds)
    return {
        'accuracy': acc,
        'f1': f1,
        'precision': precision,
        'recall': recall
    }


## training
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments

# https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/trainer.html#transformers.TrainingArguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',          # output directory
    num_train_epochs=1,              # total number of training epochs
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,  # batch size per device during training
    per_device_eval_batch_size=8,   # batch size for evaluation
    warmup_steps=500,                # number of warmup steps for learning rate scheduler
    weight_decay=0.01,               # strength of weight decay
    logging_dir='./logs',            # directory for storing logs
    logging_steps=100,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,                         # the instantiated  Transformers model to be trained
    args=training_args,                  # training arguments, defined above
    train_dataset=dataset_train,         # training dataset
    eval_dataset=dataset_val             # evaluation dataset
)

trainer.train()
# output: TrainOutput(global_step=181, training_loss=nan)
trainer.evaluate()
# output: 
[2 2 2 0 0 2 2 2 0 2 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 2 0 2 2 2 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 2 0 0 2 0 0 0 2
 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2
 2 0 2 0 0 2 2 2 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 2 0 2 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 2 2 0 0
 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 2 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 2 2
 0 2 2 2 0 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 2 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 2 0 2 2 2 0 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 2 0 2 2 2]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

{'epoch': 1.0,
 'eval_accuracy': 0.5137254901960784,
 'eval_f1': 0.6787564766839378,
 'eval_loss': nan,
 'eval_precision': 0.5137254901960784,
 'eval_recall': 1.0}
```

**Edit:**  I've also opened a github issue with a but more detailed description of the issue here: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/9160

Comment: Try running on CPU, I had experience this, and when I tried with cpu, it worked fine.

Comment: I have to use a GPU unfortunately, because I want to fine-tune the model on over 276.000 sentences and that already takes many hours on GPU

Comment: Just run a test with small amount of samples on GPU and CPU.

Answer (score 1):

I received a good answer from the HuggingFace team on github. The issue was the `model.half()`, which has the advantage of increasing speed and reducing memory usage, but it also changes the model in a way that it produces the error. removing the `model.half()` solved the issue for me. For details, see https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/9160